# What is the easiest way to upload video and audio content?

Tags: media, files

I am creating a website archive that will allow users to upload various different types of media content including video, audio, images, documents and text. I want to make it easy for users to upload the media content to the site.

Is it better to upload directly to the website hosting itself or to use a third party video and audio hosting like YouTube and SoundCloud?

Either way how can it be made as easy as possible for the user to upload the media content?

Comment: Checkout media module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a media management suite that integrates with as many third party hosting providers as possible. It means less work for you, less complexity, and less bandwidth on your server for which you have to pay.

Good suite's include, but are not limited to:

[Scald](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald)

> Scald is a popular and flexible way to handle media in Drupal.
>
> Scald can handle images, video, audio, tweets and even Flash files.
>   Scald works with YouTube, Vimeo, Soundcloud and other many other
>   providers.

and [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)

> The Media module provides an extensible framework for managing files
>   and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your
>   own site or a 3rd party site - it is commonly referred to as a 'file
>   browser to the internet'.

For a front end media solution you can look at [MediaFront](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront)

> The MediaFront module is a front end media solution for Drupal. It
>   employs an innovative and intuitive administration interface that
>   allows the website administrator to completely customize the front end
>   media experience for their users without writing any code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) module

> The filedepot module is full featured Document Management module that
>   has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated
>   file management module supporting role and user based security.
>   Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect
>   documents for safe access and distribution.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that.  Does it include a media player?

Answer (score 1):

Some more modules not mentioned yet in any of the previous answers ...

## Modules with a stable D7 release

#### Take Control (D6 and D7)

Here is a quote about the [Take Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/take_control) module (from its project page):

> ... is a set of set of modules for Drupal for managing various administrative tasks particularly related to the file system. Beginning with version 2.0, the module has been refactored into a core/add-on architecture, where a core module take_control provides common routines and settings, whereas the bulk of front-end user interaction comes from add-on modules (e.g. file browser etc).
>
> Currently, there are 2 add-on modules:
>
> 1. **File Browser**: A complete File Browser/File Manager for Drupal. Allows you to manage your Drupal file-system directly through Drupal without needing FTP or your Hosting Control Panel access.
> 2. **Quick Permissions**: Many Drupal administrators are troubled by the: Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
>    directive in Drupal file-system root's .htaccess file that effectively prevents write access to the file-system folder outside Drupal.
>    This module allows you to take control of the file-system folder by specifying custom permissions on it from Drupal. Additionally, you can specify custom permission / delete any directory/file owned by Drupal using this module.

#### Document (D6 and D7)

The [Document](https://www.drupal.org/project/document) module is a *Document Management System* for Drupal. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Features:
>
> - Complete integration with Drupal node system. This module adds a custom Node Type, Document. Each Document you create is a Drupal node, and hence enjoys all features available to a node.
> - Support for Document revisions/versioning - This module allows you to maintain multiple versions/revisions of the same document.
> - Views 2 Integration - The custom fields added by the module to the Document node type are accessible in Views, plus the module provides some useful out-of-the box Views.
> - Theming support
> - Searching - The documents being nodes are fully indexable by the Drupal search system. In addition, the module provides its own custom search for Documents.
> - A couple of blocks are available for document search that can be placed flexibly in your theme layout.

#### elFinder file manager (D7)

The [elFinder](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) module integrates with [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder), which is a open source AJAX file manager.  Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Features:
>
> - Integrated with [WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) capable editors: CKEditor, FCKeditor, TinyMCE, BUEditor (D6), jWYSIWYG (D6), YUI, WYMeditor.
> - Multiple file upload.
> - File copying/moving with Drag & Drop support.
> - Quick file and directory rename.
> - Image resizing.
> - Lightbox-preview.
> - Context menu with generic file/directory operations.
> - Inline text file editing.
> - Favourites directory list.
> - Directory selection history.
> - Working with archives.
> - File descriptions.

#### CMIS API (D7)

The [CMIS API](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis) module aims to provide a generic API for integrating with [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) compliant Enterprise CMS (ECM) systems.

## Modules with an unstable D7 release or for D6 only

There are a few more modules that might look like a possible fit, though they are, in general, perceived as rather buggy / unstaled, or only support old (D6) Drupal releases so far. Below are some more details about those modules.

#### Media Browser Plus (D7, though only a beta version)

There is also the [Media Browser Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) module, which is an enhancement module for the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/node/604018) module, with additions such as:

- Adding tags to media when uploading.
- Searching media.
- Hierarchical taxonomy based organization e.g. “folders".
- Mirroring folder taxonomy to filesystem"
- Drag & Drop to move files between folders.
- Multi selection of files.
- Bulk operations on files.
- Media Basked to download multiple files at once.

#### Asset (D7, though only a beta version)

Here is a quote about the [Asset](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset) module (from its project page):

> ... proposes a new approach to the media management in Drupal, resolving a long-standing problem of reusable media files (images, videos, documents, etc) that evolved into the problem of reusable media content (images/videos/documents/etc with the attached content like description/licence/etc).
>
> The Asset module provides new entity called Media Asset and the set of Media Assets examples (Image, Video, Audio, Document, Image Gallery, Free HTML), which can be enabled optionally.

#### Web File Manager (D6)

The '[Web File Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/webfm)' module is for D6 only. And issue [WebFM for Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/604018) has status *Closed (Won't fix)*. But there is also an ongoing discussion about a [Ground-up rewrite of WebFM](https://www.drupal.org/node/592956).